# get the index of dynamic input array using in jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

am trying to get the index of dynamic input tags

1. html

   ```
   <input type="text" name="test[]" value='1'>
   <input type="text" name="test[]" value='2'>
   <input type="text" name="test[]" value='3'>
   ```
2. validate.js

   ```
   rules: {
       "test[]" : { 
           required : true
        }
   },
   messages: {
       "test[]" : {
           required : function ( r, i ) {
                return " the [index]st input required"; 
                **// i need to get the index of the current input(or select) tags**
           }}}
   ```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `name="test[]"`?

Comment: ooooops yeah it's name="test[]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to the callback function is the element. You can use the jQuery `.index()` method to get its index within the collection.

```
messages: {
    "test[]": {
        required: function(params, element) {
            var index = $("input[name=test\[\]]").index(element) + 1;
            return "Input #" + index + " required";
        }
    }
}
```